# Cyclotomic Polynomial $\Phi_p(x)$ Expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

On page 310 of Dummit & Foote, the following expansion is given for prime $p$.

$$\Phi_p(x)=\frac{x^p-1}{x-1}=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+x+1.$$

This is a very basic question, but how does the expansion come about?

Comment: “cyclomatic”. : ⟩ It’s [cyclotomic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyclotomic), meaning “circle cutting”. (Compare “tomography” meaning “cut drawing”.)

Comment: Haha, thank you, fixed it.

Comment: we have the inductive relationship $$\frac{x^p-1}{x-1} = \frac{x^p-x^{p-1}+x^{p-1}-1}{x-1} = x^{p-1} +\frac{x_{p-1}-1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually has nothing to do with p being a prime number. If you multiply by $(x-1)$ the right hand side you get :

$$ (x-1)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} x^{k+1} - x^k = x^p -1$$

Notice that 1 is a root of the polynomial $x^p-1$ so it is natural to try and find a polynomial P such that $P = \dfrac{x^p-1}{x-1}$. One can also notice that it is simply a geometric sum (the proof of the geometric sum is actually the same as the one I provided!)